# How should I animate my View so that it looks like it's "rolling"?

Tags: android, animation, 3d

I want to move a View from the top to the bottom of the screen and I know how to use animations for layouts in Android. However the problem is that I don't just want to move it from the top to the bottom; I want to make it look like it's "rolling". How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: have u got any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need a combination of translation and rotation animation. Use [AnimationSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html) for this.
Further Rotation should be done along x axis so that it gives a effect of rolling. 
Refer [Rotate3dAnimation](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/Rotate3dAnimation.html) for this